# Finalizing editing in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I using jqgrid with great succes in the following way:

1. The data is loaded from the server as JSON
2. The user do inline editing
3. When a save-button is clicked all the data is serialized using:

   var data = $("#mygrid").getRowData();

   var datajson = JSON.stringify(data);

The problem with this aproach is that I will get the input elements in my json-data if the user has not pressed return or moved away from the edited cell. Is there any way to end edit mode i jqgrid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [saveRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#saverow) to save the data.

To use [saveRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#saverow) you have to know the row id of the current editable row. You can for example save the rowid of the current editing in a variable (before you call [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow)) and use the value for calling of the `saveRow` method.

**UPDATED:** see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SaveRow.htm). First select some row, modify the values and then click on the "Save current editing row" button. You will see that the changes will be saves.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't do it. saveRow calls the method to save the row, but the cell is still in edit mode.

Comment: @Bebben: You made some error in your implementation. I added the demo which demonstrate that the usage of `saveRow` work. If you need save the data on the server instead of local saving, you should use other parameters of `saveRow`: read exactly the link of the `saveRow` which I posted you.

Comment: Thank you Oleg! Works like a charm now! I think the problem was that I had my grid in celledit, and before I can call saveRow I must call cellEdit. Now I start of by setting all rows in edit mode, and before submit call saveRow on all the rows. Thanks!

Comment: @HardikMishra: I'm glad to know this. You are welcome! I recommend you additionally to use `keys: true` option of inline editing. If you use new version of jQuery the usage of new [jQuery.unload](http://api.jquery.com/unload/) event could be also interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by triggering "keydown" ENTER event on element:

```
editoptions: {
                    dataInit: function(elem) {
                        $(elem).datetimepicker({
                            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                            onClose: function(datetimeText, datepickerInstance) {
                                $(elem).trigger($.Event( "keydown", { keyCode: $.ui.keyCode.ENTER } ))
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use remote submit for each cell, and as I used "contenteditable" div for cell editor (for multiline text), i wanted to finish cell editing with ctrl-enter.

( Based on Oleg's answer and [How to close cell-editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508882/how-to-close-cell-editor) and http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing )

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var grid,currentCell;
    $(".jqGrid_wrapper").on("keydown","div[contenteditable]",function (e) { 
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13) 
        { 
            grid.jqGrid("saveCell",currentCell.iRow,currentCell.iCol);
            return false; 
        }

        return true; 
    });
    grid=$("#table_list_2");
    grid.jqGrid({
        url: ...
        cellEdit: true,
        cellsubmit: 'remote',
        cellurl: '..',    

        beforeEditCell: function(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
            currentCell={
                   rowid:rowid, cellname:cellname, value:value, iRow:iRow, iCol:iCol
            }
        }               
    });
});
```