# jqgrid - save data for inline editing

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid. My requirement was "load the grid with ALL ROWS IN EDIT MODE by default". So I used Oleg answer in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170260/jqgrid-all-rows-in-inline-edit-mode-by-default)

Now. I want to save data on each cell that has data. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problem why one should not makes ALL ROWS IN EDIT MODE is the fact that all the change are not saved. Such grids have some other disadvantages: sorting is disabled for example. So you have to provide some *additional interface* like "Save all changes" button outside of the grid. You should call `saveRow` on every row in the save way like you called `editRow` at the beginning. See [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4804986/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16309828/315935) or you can just place the part of code inside of `$th.click(function () {...})` from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9290716/315935) in your `click` event handler of "Save all changes" button.

Comment: @user3833823: You are welcome! Could you create the solution based on my suggestions?

Comment: I will create that one later. I will let you know.